# How do I use the INSERT INTO query in Access to insert a record that is from a variable

Tags: sql, .net, database

How do I use the `INSERT INTO` command from .NET to insert the contents of a variable Using `CommandText`.

Here is what I have:

(On button press)

```
string test = txtFirstName.Text;
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName) Values (test)";
```

Integers and strings in quotes work, just not from a variable, and I need the program to write the text that is in the textbox to the database.

I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: `Values ('" + test + "')";` but you **really** should use parametrized queries, they are designed for this - [Using parameters in SQL statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: have a look at [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) for info on SQL parameters

Answer (score 2):

Your error happens because your string value is improperly formed. This is besides your syntax error.
Feeding off @Alex K.

```
string test = txtFirstName.Text;
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName) Values (@1)";
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", test);
```

This is  better than this

```
string test = txtFirstName.Text;
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Store (FirstName) Values ('" + test.Replace("'", "''") + "')";
```

What if `txtFirstName.Text` has `'`, like in "O'Neal"? - the first example takes care of that as well, besides sql injection